# Page loading mask while browser renders

Tags: javascript, rendering

Is there a way to show a "page loading" mask tied to the *rendering* of a page.

We have tried the usual solutions of adding the show / hide triggers either side of our load function, however the issue is with the render of the page, rather than the loading. The mask is dismissed after ~5ms but Chrome then takes approx 2.5 secs to render the page.

When profiling in Chrome's Performance tab the bottleneck is the "Composite Layers" renderer. This is understandable as we're positioning up to 70 thumbnails over a svg background.

There's a separate reason for the mask as there's a second between the assets loading and the renderer completing when the assets are visible "piled up" at the top of the page.

Comment: There's always the hacky solution of using `setInterval` to artificially extend your loading spinner by a second, if absolutely all else fails..